# Find the arithmetic mean of all the elements in a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let Q be the set of positive rational numbers less than 1, which can be expressed with a 10-digit period in decimal representation in which all 10 digits are distinct(for example 0.12345678901234567890.....).
Find the arithmetic mean of all elements in Q.
I decided to sum all the numbers, which came out to be 1/2, which divided by 10! gives the answer. However I'm not sure whether the answer is right as I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. This is not a site for "do it for me" questions.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize, will edit

Comment: Are you getting $1\over2$ for the answer, or $1\over2\cdot10!$?

Comment: The summation of the numbers is 1/2 and the final answer is 1/2.10!

Comment: What do you mean by "summation of the numbers"? One of the numbers is $0.98765432109876543210\ldots$, after all, which is already greater than $1/2$.

Comment: " I decided to sum all the numbers, which came out to be 1/2"  How did you sum the numbers to $\frac 12$??????

Comment: I am *truly* curious how you figured the sum of the numbers was $\frac 12$.  I imagine whatever method you used was actually to calculate the *average*.

Comment: Also notice $\frac 1{2*10!} \approx 1.3778659611992945326278659611993e-7= 0.00000013778659611992945326278659611993....< 0.01234567890123456789....$ and is therefore smaller than *ANY* of the numbers.  So that can't be the average if it is *smaller* than *all* the numbers.

Comment: My bad, apparently I had divided by 10! somewhere in a previous step, which was wrong obviously. Got the answer now though, so thanks

Comment: A $10$ digit period doesn't mean that the period starts with the first digit after the decimal point. Consider, for example, $\displaystyle0.101234567890123456789...=0.1(0123456789)=\frac{10123456788}{10^{11}-10}$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Say $x$ is one of those numbers. Say $y$ is the number obtained by replacing each digit $d_j$ in $x$ with the digit $9-d_j$. What is $x+y$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider it digit by digit.

Common sense and symmetry tells us there were be as many numbers with $k$ as the first digit as any other.  And we can easily verify that.  The usual fear that a 10 digit number can't start with $0$ does not apply, etc.

If we average the values the first digit contribute we get the average value of the first digit is $\frac {\sum_{i=0}^9 i}{10}*10^{-1} = .45$.

If we do that for each digit we get the sum of the average values that the individual contributes = the average values of the numbers is $.45 + .045 +.... + 4.5\times 10^{-k} + .... = 0.49999999999..... = 0.5$.

The average is, unsurprisingly $\frac 12$.

====

Another way to do it

every number is in the form $0.d_1d_2....d_9d_{10} \times 100000000010000000001000000000......$

For every $0.d_1d_2....d_9d_{10}......$ there is a corresdoing number $0.(9-d_1)(9-d_2)....(9-d_9)(9-d_{10})......$.  This number is distinct from its original counter part (because $d_i = 9 - d_i$ is impossible for any $i$ much less all ten).  So the sum of these two numbers is $0.999999999.......=1$.

So there are $10!$ such numbers and there are $\frac {10!}2$ such pairs.  So the sum of all these numbers is $1*\frac {10!}2$.

SO the average of these numbers is $\frac {\frac {10!}2}{10!} = \frac 12$.

It actually does not matter that there are $10!$ such pairs.  We don't care how many pairs there are.  As all pairs add to $1$ and the average of each pair is $\frac 12$, the average of all the numbers will be the average of the averages of the pairs.  And as that is constant the average is $\frac 12$.